# Ruby on Rails & FullCalendar: Is there any way to add a link to the title header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, fullcalendar, erb

I have a page in my simple application that displays a calendar with the jQuery plugin http://fullcalendar.io/.

I want to add a link to the title such that the user gets navigated somewhere else to a different view. Is this possible? The calendar itself has poor documentation. Specifically I want to add a FontAwesome icon and have it redirect the user on click.

I know that customizing the title is pretty easy – just specify the custom title like this:

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prevYear,nextYear',
      center: 'title',           
    },
    titleFormat: '[Hello, World!]'
  });
</script>
```

However, I am trying to add a link next to the calendar using a Rails helper `link_to`. Is this possible? Here is my attempt, but it does not work:

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prevYear,nextYear',
      center: 'title',
    },
    titleFormat: '[<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-icon"></i>'.html_safe, some_path %>']'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on this line:

```html
    titleFormat: '[<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-icon"></i>'.html_safe, some_path %>']'
```

There is an extra single quote after the `%>`. Try this:

```html
    titleFormat: '[<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-icon"></i>'.html_safe, some_path %>]'
```

If you still have a problem after fixing that, try looking into what FullCalendar’s `titleFormat` property supports. I don’t know if FullCalendar tries to allow you to put arbitrary HTML into that property – [that property’s docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/titleFormat/) don’t make it clear. You could check by looking in the rest of [FullCalendar’s documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) or its [source code that handles that property](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=titleFormat).

Your use of [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) looks good to me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to support html... Thanks for editing and trying to help me though